# Telerik Ajax MVC Grid - How can I restore filter and paging state on Back button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter, grid, telerik, viewstate

how can I restore Telerik Grid filters when I land on my page using the back button?

Two problems I am facing:

- prevent the Grid from getting the data before I have set the filter information
- update the column header UI to show the filter information

Comment: I don't think this can be done in other way than saving the filters in your custom object somehow and then reapplying them on page load (checking whether there are saved filter expressions present). To update the column header filter UI, access the column and set the selected filter function/pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Use the application history point feature:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488548.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488025.aspx

HTH.